# Reading word2vec Binary File in Python

Tags: python, file, binary, binaryfiles, word2vec

I am trying to read the a bin file. It has millions of lines of a word followed by space separated numbers.

So, far in Python I havent been able to  get a line printed, it either gives gibberish or wrong output.

```
with open('GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin', mode='rb') as file: # b is important -> binary
    for line in file.readline():
        print(line)
```

How should I read a binary file line by line?

Answer (score 2):

Binary files tend to not be line-oriented. They also will show gibberish when printed. So your code is working, but your expectations are wrong.

What's your ultimate goal? If it's to have usable word-vectors, you probably want to use some pre-existing `Word2Vec` library, such as `gensim` in Python.

In such a library, you can also view the source-code for reading the `.bin` word-vectors format, as a model to learn from, if for some reason you really do need to write your own reading code. For example, here's the gensim source code that reads word-vector files in the format written by the original `word2vec.c` code from Google:

https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/3c3506d51a2caf6b890de3b1b32a8b85f7566ca5/gensim/models/utils_any2vec.py#L123

(It's more often used from the `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format()` public API method.)